# Golang data race even with mutex for custom concurrent maps

Tags: go, concurrency, benchmarking, goroutine

Here is a simple concurrent map that I wrote for learning purpose

```
    package concurrent_hashmap

    import (
        "hash/fnv"
        "sync"
    )

    type ConcurrentMap struct {
        buckets []ThreadSafeMap
        bucketCount uint32
    }

    type ThreadSafeMap struct {
        mapLock sync.RWMutex
        hashMap map[string]interface{}
    }

    func NewConcurrentMap(bucketSize uint32) *ConcurrentMap {
        var threadSafeMapInstance ThreadSafeMap
        var bucketOfThreadSafeMap []ThreadSafeMap

        for i := 0; i <= int(bucketSize); i++ {
            threadSafeMapInstance = ThreadSafeMap{sync.RWMutex{}, make(map[string]interface{})}
            bucketOfThreadSafeMap = append(bucketOfThreadSafeMap, threadSafeMapInstance)
        }

        return &ConcurrentMap{bucketOfThreadSafeMap, bucketSize}
    }

    func (cMap *ConcurrentMap) Put(key string, val interface{}) {
        bucketIndex := hash(key) % cMap.bucketCount
        bucket := cMap.buckets[bucketIndex]
        bucket.mapLock.Lock()
        bucket.hashMap[key] = val
        bucket.mapLock.Unlock()
    }

    // Helper
    func hash(s string) uint32 {
        h := fnv.New32a()
        h.Write([]byte(s))
        return h.Sum32()
    }
```

I am trying to write a simple benchmark and I find that synchronize access will work correctly but concurrent access will get

```
fatal error: concurrent map writes
```

Here is my benchmark run with `go test -bench=. -race`

```
package concurrent_hashmap

import (
    "testing"
    "runtime"
    "math/rand"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
)
// Concurrent does not work
func BenchmarkMyFunc(b *testing.B) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())

    my_map := NewConcurrentMap(uint32(4))
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        go insert(my_map, wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}

func insert(my_map *ConcurrentMap, wg sync.WaitGroup) {
    wg.Add(1)
    var rand_int int
    for element_num := 0; element_num < 1000; element_num++ {
        rand_int = rand.Intn(100)
        my_map.Put(strconv.Itoa(rand_int), rand_int)
    }
    defer wg.Done()
}

// This works
func BenchmarkMyFuncSynchronize(b *testing.B) {
    my_map := NewConcurrentMap(uint32(4))
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        my_map.Put(strconv.Itoa(123), 123)
    }
}
```

The `WARNING: DATA RACE` is saying that `bucket.hashMap[key] = val` is causing the problem, but I am confused on why that is possible, since I lock that logic whenever write is happening.

I think I am missing something basic, can someone point out my mistake?

Thanks

Edit1:

Not sure if this helps but here is what my mutex looks like if I don't lock anything

```
{{0 0} 0 0 0 0}
```

Here is what it looks like if I lock the write

```
{{1 0} 0 0 -1073741824 0}
```

Not sure why my [readerCount](https://golang.org/src/sync/rwmutex.go) is a low negative number

Edit:2

I think I find where the issue is at, but not sure why I have to code that way

The issue is

```
type ThreadSafeMap struct {
    mapLock sync.RWMutex // This is causing problem
    hashMap map[string]interface{}
}
```

it should be

```
type ThreadSafeMap struct {
    mapLock *sync.RWMutex
    hashMap map[string]interface{}
}
```

Another weird thing is that in `Put` if I put print statement inside lock

```
bucket.mapLock.Lock()
fmt.Println("start")
fmt.Println(bucket)
fmt.Println(bucketIndex)
fmt.Println(bucket.mapLock)
fmt.Println(&bucket.mapLock)
bucket.hashMap[key] = val
defer bucket.mapLock.Unlock()
```

The following prints is possible

```
start
start
{0x4212861c0 map[123:123]}
{0x4212241c0 map[123:123]}
```

Its weird because each `start` printout should be follow with 4 lines of bucket info since you cannot have `start` back to back because that would indicate that multiple thread is access the line inside lock

Also for some reason each `bucket.mapLock` have different address even if I make the bucketIndex static, that indicate that I am not even accessing the same lock.

But despite the above weirdness changing mutex to pointer solves my problem

I would love to find out why I need pointers for mutex and why the prints seem to indicate multiple thread is accessing the lock and why each lock has different address.

Comment: I don't know what the race is, but as an aside, you should really use `defer` to unlock your mutex (in case there's a panic).

Comment: Also not the race, but `i <= int(bucketSize)` should be `i < int(bucketSize)`.

Comment: I think line 88 of the file you linked to explains why `readerCount` is a low negative number.

Comment: @smarx oh readerCount now make sense, thanks for pointing that out, and thanks for pointing out the boundary logic error I had earlier

Comment: Run `go vet` on your code. You're copying the Mutexes and WaitGroups, and you can't add to the wait group after the goroutine is already dispatched.

Comment: The `print` output seems fine to me... there are multiple `maps`, so multiple goroutines can simultaneously be making modifications (as long as they're not modifying the same map). Similarly, there should be *n* different locks for the *n* different `maps`, so the different addresses seem fine.

Comment: Oh, I think @JimB nails it with the comment about copying... I believe you could also fix this by putting pointers to `ThreadSafeMap`s in your `ConcurrentMap` instead.

Comment: @smarx sorry I should clarify that I fixed the bucket index by inserting the same element for all goroutines, that is why it is weird.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Then I think @JimB's comment explains what you saw (different locks because they were copied).

Comment: @JimB @smarx Sorry, I think I am not getting it, why is passing `waitgroup` to a function influencing the `mutex` in the struct?

Comment: @smarx I think this line `ThreadSafeMap{sync.RWMutex{}, make(map[string]interface{})}` should ensure I get a new mutex for every bucket

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the statement

```
bucket := cMap.buckets[bucketIndex]
```

`bucket` now contains copy of the `ThreadSafeMap` at that index. As `sync.RWMutex` is stored as value, a copy of it is made while assigning. But map  maps hold references to an underlying data structure, so the copy of the pointer or the same map is passed. The code locks a copy of the lock while writing to a single map, which cause the problem.

Thats why you don't face any problem when you change `sync.RWMutex` to `*sync.RWMutex`. It's better to store reference to structure in map as shown.

```
package concurrent_hashmap

import (
    "hash/fnv"
    "sync"
)

type ConcurrentMap struct {
    buckets     []*ThreadSafeMap
    bucketCount uint32
}

type ThreadSafeMap struct {
    mapLock sync.RWMutex
    hashMap map[string]interface{}
}

func NewConcurrentMap(bucketSize uint32) *ConcurrentMap {
    var threadSafeMapInstance *ThreadSafeMap
    var bucketOfThreadSafeMap []*ThreadSafeMap

    for i := 0; i <= int(bucketSize); i++ {
        threadSafeMapInstance = &ThreadSafeMap{sync.RWMutex{}, make(map[string]interface{})}
        bucketOfThreadSafeMap = append(bucketOfThreadSafeMap, threadSafeMapInstance)
    }

    return &ConcurrentMap{bucketOfThreadSafeMap, bucketSize}
}

func (cMap *ConcurrentMap) Put(key string, val interface{}) {
    bucketIndex := hash(key) % cMap.bucketCount
    bucket := cMap.buckets[bucketIndex]
    bucket.mapLock.Lock()
    bucket.hashMap[key] = val
    bucket.mapLock.Unlock()
}

// Helper
func hash(s string) uint32 {
    h := fnv.New32a()
    h.Write([]byte(s))
    return h.Sum32()
}
```

It's possible to validate the scenario by modifying the function `Put` as follows

```
func (cMap *ConcurrentMap) Put(key string, val interface{}) {
    //fmt.Println("index", key)
    bucketIndex := 1
    bucket := cMap.buckets[bucketIndex]
    fmt.Printf("%p %p\n", &(bucket.mapLock), bucket.hashMap)
}
```